# How can I hide/nest .js files transpiled from .tsx files?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tsx

Visual Studio is not properly nesting(like it does with js.map files) or hiding(like non-core projects) my js files created by the typescript compiler in my asp.net mvc core project.  This is polluting my Solution Explorer.

Here is an image of the current behavior.

[image: showing invalid nesting]

I wanted to know how I can either hide the js file, or nest it.  In a way that doesn't involve doing it individually for each file.

Comment: @Ross I added some edits why your link won't solve my problem.  The first is that it's manual, I would need to do something for each new tsx file I added.  The second is that all of those solutions apply to framework projects, not .net core projects.